# changing one value according to some conditions in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this one

```
session <- c(rep(34,8), rep(28,8))
trial_index <- c(rep(2,4),rep(5,4),rep(6,4),rep(8,4))
label <- c(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),4))
time <- c(10,2,7,40,4,3,6,20,5,3,5,15,4,2,3,17)
data <-data.frame(session, trial_index,label,time)
```

What I would like to do is to change the value of "d" for each trial index and session. The value of each d should be d = d-c-b-a. For example, for session 34 trial index 2, d should be 40 - 7 - 2 - 10. I don´t need to change the values of a b and c. I have no clue of how to do this, so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly convoluted approach perhaps but here you go.

1) Shift the column down so that you get the values of a, b, c next to d.

```
data <- data %>% mutate(time2 = lag(time), time3 = lag(time2), time4 = lag(time3))
```

Thanks for the suggestion to do the mutation in one line, David!

2) Perform the calculation for label equaling d while remaining is left untouched.

```
data <- transform(data, time = ifelse(label == 'd', time-time2-time3-time4, time))
```

3) Remove the three unwanted columns created earlier:

```
data <- data[-c(5, 6, 7)]
```

Output:

```
   session trial_index label time
1       34           2     a   10
2       34           2     b    2
3       34           2     c    7
4       34           2     d   21
5       34           5     a    4
6       34           5     b    3
7       34           5     c    6
8       34           5     d    7
9       28           6     a    5
10      28           6     b    3
11      28           6     c    5
12      28           6     d    2
13      28           8     a    4
14      28           8     b    2
15      28           8     c    3
16      28           8     d    8
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks a lot. Was not aware of it. Updated :)

Answer (score 4):

One approach of doing this is by rearranging your data so that the labels become individual columns for each `session-trial_index` combination. Then the calculation for d is then a simple column based subtraction. Post this you can convert the data back into this original form.

A example implementation of the same is below

```
library(tidyr) # To rearrange the data
library(dplyr) # To do the subtraction

data <- tidyr::spread(data, key = label, value = time) %>% # Makes labels as columns
  dplyr::mutate(d = d - c - b - a) %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = label, value = time,-session,-trial_index) # Convert back
```

The output of this code is

```
| session| trial_index|label | time|
|-------:|-----------:|:-----|----:|
|      34|           2|a     |   10|
|      34|           2|b     |    2|
|      34|           2|c     |    7|
|      34|           2|d     |   21|
|      34|           5|a     |    4|
|      34|           5|b     |    3|
|      34|           5|c     |    6|
|      34|           5|d     |    7|
|      28|           6|a     |    5|
|      28|           6|b     |    3|
|      28|           6|c     |    5|
|      28|           6|d     |    2|
|      28|           8|a     |    4|
|      28|           8|b     |    2|
|      28|           8|c     |    3|
|      28|           8|d     |    8|
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works very well! I was wondering. What if I have an additional variable (time2) and I want to do the same thing? Do I need to do it separately for each?

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation I guess. Probably a function would help but it wouldn't be elegant. I think some of the other solutions may work better in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
newdf <- data[, list(new=time[label=='d'] - time[label=='c'] - time[label=='b'] - time[label=='a']) ,list(session, trial_index)]
data <- merge(data,newdf)
data[label=='d',time := new]
data[,new := NULL]
```

Note that the data will reorder because of the merge so if you need to retain this then just add an index first and then reorder:

```
data[,index:=1:nrow(data)]
newdf <- data[, list(new=time[label=='d'] - time[label=='c'] - time[label=='b'] - time[label=='a']) ,list(session, trial_index)]
data <- merge(data,newdf)
data[label=='d',time := new]
data[,new := NULL]
data <- data[order(index),]
data[,index:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using data.table

```
library(data.table)

## Just subset everything from "d" (as the order doesn't really matter) by group
d <- setDT(data)[, Reduce(`-`, rev(time)), by = .(session, trial_index)]$V1

## Insert the results only for "d" 
data[label == "d", time := d]

data
#     session trial_index label time
#  1:      34           2     a   10
#  2:      34           2     b    2
#  3:      34           2     c    7
#  4:      34           2     d   21
#  5:      34           5     a    4
#  6:      34           5     b    3
#  7:      34           5     c    6
#  8:      34           5     d    7
#  9:      28           6     a    5
# 10:      28           6     b    3
# 11:      28           6     c    5
# 12:      28           6     d    2
# 13:      28           8     a    4
# 14:      28           8     b    2
# 15:      28           8     c    3
# 16:      28           8     d    8
```

Comment: Does this assume time is ordered by label a < b < c < d ?

Comment: I like your solution as I have worked with data.table before. However, I have problems to understand this part of the code Reduce(`-`, rev(time)). I would appreciate if you could explain me that. Also,  what if I have an additional variable (time2) and I want to do the same thing? Do I need to do it separately for each? Thanks

Comment: @rookie it only assumes that "d" is last, all the rest of the order doesn't matter according to the math rules.

Comment: @unomas83. The `Reduce` is just subsetting each value from the precious subset and eventually returning a single value. If you want to do this for several values, you will need to simply put it into `lapply(.SD, ...)` and specify `.SDcols`. You should read some data.table tutorials as Im not infront of the computer and can't write it right now, sorry.